# Should the oven heating coil stay on the whol time you are baking?

Tags: oven

We have a Frigidaire electric stove. Should the oven heating coil stay on the whole time we are cooking? For example, turn the oven to 350 for 30 minutes. Coil turns red, then goes to black, theb back to red or sometimes not back to red unless I raise the temp. a few degrees.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely No. Most electric ovens heat to certain temperatures by turning the heating element on and off with a thermostat, much like your home thermostat will keep your house hot. This is referred to as a 'Duty Cycle'. Basically, the element may come 'on' and start glowing as it heats. Once the inside of the oven reaches the desired temperature, it may turn off and cool as much as 5-15 degrees then cycle on again.

Comment: Agreed, but there is one exception: Broil. Some ovens use a thermostat with Broil (but at ~ 500 instead of 350) but I think some just leave the element on the whole time.